# File Upload to Channel via Microsoft Teams Graph Api

Tags: file-upload, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I have been trying to do a file upload to a channel using the graph Api. I can successful do an upload to my personal OneDrive, using the request https://graph.microsoft.com:443/v1.0/me/drive/root:/fileName:/content

However I am unable to upload to a channel. I have tried many combinations, but keep getting invalidRequest. Below are some of the request I have tried:

https://graph.microsoft.com:443/v1.0/groups/groupID/drive/items/channelID:/iconfinder_13_3561846_32.png:/content

https://graph.microsoft.com:443/v1.0/groups/groupID/drive/items/channelName:/iconfinder_13_3561846_32.png:/content

I have also tried inputting the channel ID in various ways:

xx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@thread.tacv2
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@thread.tacv2
xx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what I was doing wrong. For anybody else who is having an issue, you have to get the folder id that backs the channel. Here is an example in C#.

```
// Get the folder of the channel (driveItem)
var item = await graphClient.Teams[teamID].Channels[channelID].FilesFolder
.Request().GetAsync();

// Do the put request
var uploadRequest = graphClient
                //.Me.Drive.Root
                .Groups[teamID]
                .Drive
                .Items[item.Id]
                .ItemWithPath(file.FileName)
                .Content.Request()
                .PutAsync<DriveItem>(file.OpenReadStream());
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours with this topic. Your solution wasn't working for me but I finally got it done. To save others I'd like to share my solution too:

I use this to get the drive item for the channel:

```
var request = graphClient.Teams[teamId].Channels[channelId].FilesFolder.Request().GetAsync();
```

And then upload with:

```
var uploadRequest = graphClient.Drives[driveItem.ParentReference.DriveId].Items[driveItem.Id].ItemWithPath("testfile.pdf").Content.Request()
                        .PutAsync<DriveItem>(System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath));
```

My application authenticates with a client secret. Maybe this makes a difference.